# We have a problem with the [english] [language]

Tags: discussion, tags

- [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) (200 questions)

  > Puzzles that crucially depend on some feature of the English language or that only work in an English formulation.
- [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) (131 questions)

  > A puzzle that heavily depends on linguistic features; for instance it may concern foreign languages, or only work in some particular language, or be built around a peculiarity of the English language.

Having read the tag wiki excerpts and looked at how these tags are being used ... I don't get it. It seems as though [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) should be a strict subset of [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), but there are many [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) questions not tagged language, and many English-specific [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) questions not tagged [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english).

### Should we clarify, update, or change our usage guidance for these tags?

Answer (score 5):

### We should merge the two tags into one.

Looking at the list of questions for each tag, there doesn't seem to be much difference in how they're actually used.

- One possibility would be to synonymise and merge [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) into [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language). After all, every puzzle which is essentially about the English language is therefore about language.
- Another would be to merge [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) into [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) (after all, this is a predominantly English-language site) and then create a new [foreign-languages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-languages) tag<sup>1</sup> for those few questions which are language-based but not specifically based on English.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This tag could also be called e.g. [non-english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-english), or even [languages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) provided we write a new tag wiki to make clear it's only for non-English languages.</sub>

Comment: I think that for many puzzles, tagging it `foreign-languages` rather than just `languages` would give part of it away. I do agree with the rest of the post, though

Comment: @Trojan Well, the same is true of almost any tag here: adding a tag can often act as a hint. That's what [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] is for.

Comment: indeed. The first suggestion still seems better to me, though :P

Comment: I don't know about others, but I think the term "foreign language" is mildly offensive.  To someone whose native language is not English, their native language certainly isn't foreign.  Perhaps "non-English" or "other languages" might be better choices.

Comment: @Gentle For better or worse, the official language of *this site* is English.

Comment: @randal'thor I'm not arguing that; I think it's appropriate to tag non-English-based puzzles with their own tag.  I just don't like the term "foreign" when describing non-English languages, since many of them are not in fact foreign to many of our users.

Comment: Merging language into English removes the ability to categorize non-English puzzles, of which there have been a reasonable number.

Comment: @Emrakul So make a list of the non-English puzzles first, do the merge, and then retag those puzzles manually by referring to the list. (Like I did [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10408/31394), for instance. I have a *lot* of experience with retagging and merges! :-) )

Comment: @rand What would we be retagging them to, at that point? Presumably [language], or some other kind of language catch-all tag...

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, I guess [language] or [foreign-languages] or maybe [non-english] as GPR suggested.